# PreferenceFragment compile but my program doesn't work . What is the matter ? Exception code is here

Tags: android, android-emulator, nullpointerexception, android-logcat, preferencefragment

```
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.otobusumnerede/com.otobusumnerede.AyarlarActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at com.otobusumnerede.AyarlarActivity.onCreate(AyarlarActivity.java:24)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-04 11:09:41.524: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  ... 11 more
03-04 11:24:14.452: E/Trace(1311): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.otobusumnerede/com.otobusumnerede.AyarlarActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.otobusumnerede.AyarlarActivity.onCreate(AyarlarActivity.java:25)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-04 11:24:44.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: There is a `NullPointerException` @ line 25 `AyarlarActivity.java`. Fix it

Comment: post the AyarlarActivity.java

Comment: public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) this 25.line

Comment: I found by count.So i'm not sure :)

Comment: @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);} it may.

Answer (score 0):

If you can copy text from your activity and paste it, or atleast paste line no.25 of your code, its easier to help you.

Going by as it is so early in your activity, check `onCreate()` first

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutxml);
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourimageviewid); //just an example
```

1. make sure to call `setContentView()` before any `findViewById`
2. check if you have declared, initialized your variables properly
3. if so, look for a value that could be null

Comment: Yes, It fixed user2450263

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow